# Does kafka support TLS 1.3 for Java8

Tags: java, apache-kafka, java-8, tls1.3

I have a setup running kafka 3.0.0. We use JDK 1.8 for our environment. We want to support TLS 1.3.

I looked up the Apache kafka documentation and added the following to kafka broker server.properties file:

```
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.3
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.3
```

However, when I start kafka broker, I see the following error:

```
ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.3 SSLContext not available
```

I looked up on Google and it sounds like TLS 1.3 is supported on Kafka only for Java11 and above. If we are using an older Java version, TLS 1.3 is not supported.

I wanted to check here if this is true. Is there an alternative way of setting up TLS 1.3 on my setup?

Comment: Why can't you upgrade Java? Kafka supports Java 17, even

Comment: Recent patch releases of Java 8 >do< support TLS 1.3.  Check the patch version of your Java 8 installation. It is possible that something in Kafka itself is blocking this ... but that is doubtful, IMO.

Comment: It's not a question of what Kafka supports. It's a question of what Java 8 supports.